How to run prisma migration on Azure App service post-deployment?
I am creating a simple CD pipeline to deploy a Nest JS app on an Azure App Service.
I need generate prisma schema and also run prisma migrations after deployment is done.
When I try to run those with custom bash script, I get "Module not found" error".
Seems like I'm not in the correct working directory. How can I run those scripts from my deployed app folder? The script should do something similar to "cd site/wwwroot && npx prisma generate" from kudo terminal.
I don't want to put prisma commands in app service startup command since I don't want to run then every time my web app restarts. I need to run them in my cd pipeline.
Here is a sample pipeline:

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: deploy_stage
    displayName: 'Deploy Stage'
    jobs:
      - job: deploy_job
        displayName: 'Deploy to Azure App Service'
        steps:
        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            buildType: 'specific'
            project: 'project-id'
            pipeline: '6'
            buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
            downloadType: 'single'
            artifactName: 'artifact-name'
            itemPattern: '**/artifact-name.zip'
            downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

        - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
          inputs:
            ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
            azureSubscription: 'azureSubscriptionId'
            appType: 'webAppLinux'
            WebAppName: 'my-web-app-name'
            package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/path to artifact'

        - script: 'node node_modules/prisma/build/index.js generate'
          workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
          displayName: 'Generate prisma types'

        - script: 'node node_modules/prisma/build/index.js migrate deploy'
          workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
          displayName: 'Apply prisma migrations'


I tried different system variables to navigate to the correct directory, but couldn't make it work.
